# What does “Nous sommes le combien aujourd'hui ?” mean?

Tags: indications-de-temps, questions, pronoms-interrogatifs

What does “Nous sommes le combien aujourd'hui ?” (formal) and “On est le combien aujourd'hui ?” (informal) mean?

https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/dates/

Answer (score 3):

That means *Quel quantième du mois sommes nous ?*, i.e.

> Which day of the month is it today?

Today's answer would be *le vingt-deux* (the twenty-two.)

Comment: Je viens d'apprendre le mot "quantième"

Comment: @TeleportingGoat En français relâché, on dit aussi *le **combientième** du mois*.

Answer (score 2):

They mean: 'what date is it today?'